# How do I display the details without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I display the details without reloading the page?
**Logic**

- the user clicks on the links;
- result: the `content` field is displayed in the Placeholder area;

[image]
[image]
[image]

**home.controller.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

exports.getHomePage = (req, res) => {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY id ASC"; // query database to get all the players

    // execute query
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }

        res.render('index.ejs', {
            title: "Welcome to DB",
            articles: result
        });
    });
};
```

**index.routes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const homeController = require('../controllers/home.controller');
router.get('/', homeController.getHomePage);
module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const articleRoutes = require('./routes/article.routes');
const homeRoutes = require('./routes/index.routes');
const port = 2000;


// create connection to database
// the mysql.createConnection function takes in a configuration object which contains host, user, password and the database name.
const db = mysql.createConnection ({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'socka'
});

// connect to database
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Connected to database');
});
global.db = db;

// configure middleware
app.set('port', process.env.port || port);                  // set express to use this port
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');                     // set express to look in this folder to render our view
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');                              // configure template engine
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                 // parse form data client
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    // configure express to use public folder
app.use(fileUpload());                                      // configure fileupload

// routes for the app
app.use('/', homeRoutes);
// app.use('/player', playerRoutes);
app.use('/article', articleRoutes);
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);

    res.render('404.ejs', {
        title: "Page Not Found",
    });

});

// set the app to listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <!-- Кодировка веб-страницы -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Настройка viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>...</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle JS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
    <!--
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</head>
<!-- <body> -->
    <body>
        <!-- class="container" -->
        <div class="container">
            
            <!-- div -->
            <div class="border border-success border-3 p-2 vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <!-- HEADER  --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- ---->
                <!-- <header class="py-4 text-center text-uppercase fs-4 bg-primary bg-gradient text-white">
                    Header
                    </header> -->
                    
                    <!-- ROW  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- --- --- -->
                    <div class="row py-3 flex-grow-1">
                        
                        <!-- LEFT MENU  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <div class="col-3 d-flex">
                            <aside class="bg-danger bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center text-dark fs-5">                                
                                <% if (articles.length > 0) { %>
                                    <ul>
                                        <% articles.forEach((article, index) => { %>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="hidden" class="articles" name="articles[]" value="<%= article.id %>">     
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.title%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.owner%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.number%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.pos%></a>
                                            </span>
                                            
                                            <!-- <th scope="row"><%= article.id %></th> -->                                                                        
                                            <!-- <td><%= article.title%></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td><%= article.content %></td>
                                            <td><%= article.background %></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td><%= article.owner %></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td>@<%= article.number %></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td>@<%= article.pos %></td>
                                            <td>@<%= article.lang %></td> -->
                                        </li>
                                        <%})%>
                                    </ul>
                                <%}%>
                                </ul>
                            </aside>
                        </div>
                        <!-- PLACEHOLDER  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <div class="col-9 d-flex">
                            <main class="bg-light bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-dark fs-5 border border-success border-3">
                            Placeholder
                            </main>
                        </div>
                        <!-- RIGHTBAR  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <!-- <div class="col-3 d-flex">
                            <aside class="bg-danger bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-white fs-5">
                            Right Bar
                            </aside>
                        </div> -->
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- FOOTER -->
                    <!-- <footer class="py-4 bg-info bg-gradient text-center text-uppercase fs-4 text-white">
                    Footer
                    </footer> -->
                    
                </div>
                
            </div> <!-- .container -->
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE DATABASE socka;

--
-- Структура таблицы `articles`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `background` text,
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pos` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=275 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;


--
-- Структура таблицы `articles`
--
INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `title`, `content`, `background`, `owner`, `pos`, `lang`) VALUES
(1, 'Articles-1', 'Content--Articles-1', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(2, 'Articles-1-1', 'Content--Articles-1-1', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(3, 'Articles-1-2', 'Content--Articles-1-2', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(4, 'Articles-1-3', 'Content--Articles-1-3', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(5, 'Articles-1-1-1', 'Content--Articles-1-1-1', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(6, 'Articles-1-1-2', 'Content--Articles-1-1-2', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(7, 'Articles-1-1-3', 'Content--Articles-1-1-3', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(8, 'Articles-2', 'Content--Articles-2', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(9, 'Articles-3', 'Content--Articles-3', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(10, 'Articles-4', 'Content--Articles-4', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(11, 'Articles-5', 'Content--Articles-5', NULL, NULL, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Why did not you use frontend framework such as Vue, React, ...? npmjs.com/package/express-vue

Comment: @user16806454 I'm just starting to figure out node.js ...
Do you recommend Vue, React?

Comment: Yes. Vue is easy to learn than React and both are the best frameworks to do front end

Comment: @user16806454 What is the logic for making a decision on my question?
**Logic:**
  **1.** `node.js` functionality, which is described in the question (`Master-Detail`) will not perform;
  **2.** as a result, do I need to use JS?
  **3.** And on pure JS, is it difficult and more rational to use `Vue` or `React'?
**Question:** Did I understand you correctly?